# Exec command line in Node-Webkit

Tags: command-line, node-webkit, wiremock

I'm creating a desktop manager  for [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/). Wiremock is a standalone executable `jar` that reads mock mappings from a dir named "mappings" placed in the same `jar` directory and starts a http server in localhost.

I have created some mappings (`.json` files) and I have started my server with: `java -jar /path/to/wiremock/wiremock.jar` and it works properly. It reads nice my mappings (if you `GET` `localhost:<port>/__admin` you can see the mappings)

Now, I need to start the server from `node-webkit`. I do it this way:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec("java -jar " +'"' +  WIREMOCK_PATH + "/wiremock.jar" + '"', callback);
```

And server is started, but mappings are not read! I'm executing the same `jar` file. Manually, from command line it works, but using `exec` and `node-webkit`, it doesn't.

I have changed all the permissions of Wiremock path to be all public and still not working.

Comment: I would guess you need to send the proper path to exec ... you can do it with the cwd option ... [read more](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: I'm using the proper path. Server is running, but it does not read the mappings.

Comment: are you using `__dirname` or `process.cwd()`?

Comment: My dir is not variable. `WIREMOCK_PATH` is hardcoded and is not going to change.

Comment: Try to use the `WIREMOCK_PATH` variable in the exec `exec("java -jar " +'"' +  WIREMOCK_PATH + "/wiremock.jar" + '"', {cwd: WIREMOCK_PATH}, callback);`